# Extjs 4, forms with checkboxes and loadRecord

Tags: forms, extjs, model, checkbox

In my Extjs4 application I have a grid and a form.

The user model:

```
Ext.define('TestApplication.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
      { name: 'id', type: 'int', useNull: true },
      { name: 'email', type: 'string'},
      { name: 'name', type: 'string'},
      { name: 'surname', type: 'string'}
    ],
    hasMany: { model: 'Agency', name: 'agencies' },
});
```

And the Agency:

```
Ext.define('Magellano.model.Agency', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    {name: 'id', type: 'int', useNull: true},
    {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
  ]
});
```

Then in my form I'm creating the checkboxes:

```
[...]
  initComponent: function() {
    var store = Ext.getStore('Agencies');
    var checkbox_values = {xtype: 'checkboxfield', name: 'agencies[]'};
    var checkboxes = []

    store.each(function(record){
      var checkbox = {xtype: 'checkboxfield', name: 'agency_ids',
                      boxLabel: record.get('name'), inputValue: record.get('id')};
      checkbox.checked = true;
      checkboxes.push(checkbox)
    });
    this.items = [{
      title: 'User',
      xtype: 'fieldset',
      flex: 1,
      margin: '0 5 0 0',
      items: [{
        { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'email', fieldLabel: 'Email' },
        { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'name', fieldLabel: 'Nome' },
    }, {
      title: 'Agencies',
      xtype: 'fieldset',
      flex: 1,
      items: checkboxes
    }];
[...]
```

Everything works well for sending form I am receiving all the data and can save it into database.

When user clicks on the grid the record is loaded in the form with the standard:

```
form.loadRecord(record);
```

The problem is that the checkboxes are not checked. Are there any naming conventions for checkbox elements so Extjs can detect what to set? How can I setup the relations so the form will understand what to check? Or should I do everything by hand?

Answer (score 2):

In your form, you can do something like this :

```
{
   xtype: 'checkboxfield',
   name: 'test',                                
   boxLabel: 'Test',
   inputValue: 'true',
   uncheckedValue: 'false'
}
```

Comment: I added this params to checkbox but nothing change... what is the exactly problem with checkboxs on form?

Comment: my problem was that I was using xtype: 'textfield' with inputType: 'checkbox' which appeared functional but did not function correctly until I changed the xtype.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use `someCheckbox.setValue(true)` to check a checkbox dynamically, or to uncheck `someCheckbox.setValue(false)`